# Why is there no shared_mutex or recursive_shared mutex in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, c++14

In C++11 you have `mutex`, `timed_mutex` and `recursive_mutex`. C++14 adds `shared_timed_mutex`. Is there a reason why there is no `shared_mutex`or `shared_recursive_mutex`?

Comment: Because nobody proposed them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was proposed in [**N3995: A proposal to add shared_mutex (untimed)
(Revision 2)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3995.htm)

quote:

> At the Issaquah ISO C++ meeting of 2014 shared_mutex was renamed to
>   shared_timed_mutex per proposal N3891 to follow the naming precedent
>   set by timed_mutex and recursive_timed_mutex and to leave room for an
>   untimed shared_mutex which can be more efficient on some platforms
>   than shared_timed_mutex.   This paper introduces a shared_mutex type
>   without timed locking requirement. This paper only includes the
>   proposed wording. For background for shared locking please refer to
>   N3568, N3659 and N3891.   This revision is a minor edit of an earlier
>   paper N3961 that clarifies that proposed modifications to the standard
>   be incorporated into the Concurrency Technical Specification N3993.